# Triggering events by setting values of a JQuery-UI range-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider, rangeslider

im setting both values of my range-slider with the following line: `$('...').slider( 'values', [ 0, 10000 ] );` Now i have the problem, that this line triggers two times the `change( event, ui )`-event. Is there a workaround to only trigger it one time? Or is there an other event that i could use / create to get the problem solved?

I just want to avoid sending two times an ajax-request of a huge amount of data

thanks for your replies!

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An article here for you: [Setting slider value without triggering change event](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-a-sliders-value-without-triggering-the-change-event)

If you apply something like this when you're setting values in script, you could call your ajax request outside of the change handler and after you set your slider values.